# Importing datetimes to pandas DataFrame raises OutOfBoundsDatetime error

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm trying to import data to pandas DataFrame, but getting the following error while trying to convert the `date_time` column to `datetime` object:

```
pandas.tslib.OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 1-01-19 00:00:00
```

The format of the column looks like: `Jan 19,17 05:04:50 PM`

My code is:

```
data['Date_Time'] = to_datetime(data['Date_Time']).dt.strftime('%b %d, %y %H:%M:%S ')
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 3):

I think you need [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) with parameter [`format`](http://strftime.org/):

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'Date_Time':['Jan 19,17 05:04:50 PM','Jan 19,17 05:04:50 PM']})
print (data)
               Date_Time
0  Jan 19,17 05:04:50 PM
1  Jan 19,17 05:04:50 PM

data['Date_Time'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Date_Time'], format='%b %d,%y %H:%M:%S %p')
print (data)
            Date_Time
0 2017-01-19 05:04:50
1 2017-01-19 05:04:50
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I can't use format because the format of date time column may change. That's why I'm using strftime to convert the column to one format.

Comment: I think it is very problematic, because if default parser in `to_datetime` cannot parse return error. One possible solution is add parameter `errors='coerce'` - it return `NaT` for each not parsed value.

Comment: This option is not so good for me, since I need all the dates in order  to make analysis on the data

Comment: I was worried about it... Unfortunately it is impossible in pandas, what you need.

Comment: If some not standard weird format, `parameter format` is necessary. Or some preprocessing for change formats.

Comment: Can you add all formats what are possible? Maybe you can filter them and for each group apply some different `format parameter`.

Answer (score -2):

I fixed it by using regex -  replaced bad values.

And then using pandas to_datetime function with parameter format.

Comment: This does not answer the question. You should provide code solving the problem, not just using two sentences to explain in very little detail what was done. Especially since the solution you have explained here fixed bad _input data_ which was not in the original question. IMHO, @jezrael's answer is more "correct" to the problem stated above, as it solves the problem as it is presented.