# Pandas read_SAS throwing OutOfBoundsDatetime error but no date columns are in the data set

Tags: python, pandas

So I've checked [pandas.to_datetime gives OutOfBoundsDatetime Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51383367/pandas-to-datetime-gives-outofboundsdatetime-error) adn [Importing datetimes to pandas DataFrame raises OutOfBoundsDatetime error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42107377/importing-datetimes-to-pandas-dataframe-raises-outofboundsdatetime-error) no help.

I'm trying to chunk in certain columns from a SAS dataset and none of those columns are date-time format.

Here is the error I'm getting:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OverflowError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
pandas\_libs\tslib.pyx in pandas._libs.tslib.array_with_unit_to_datetime()

pandas\_libs\tslibs\timedeltas.pyx in pandas._libs.tslibs.timedeltas.cast_from_unit()

OverflowError: int too big to convert

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

OutOfBoundsDatetime                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-2b6827de404c> in <module>
      1 chunk_list = []
      2 
----> 3 for chunk in df:
      4     chunk_filter =chunk_preprocessing(chunk)
      5     chunk_list.append(chunk)

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\io\sas\sas7bdat.py in __next__(self)
    246 
    247     def __next__(self):
--> 248         da = self.read(nrows=self.chunksize or 1)
    249         if da is None:
    250             raise StopIteration

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\io\sas\sas7bdat.py in read(self, nrows)
    631         p.read(nrows)
    632 
--> 633         rslt = self._chunk_to_dataframe()
    634         if self.index is not None:
    635             rslt = rslt.set_index(self.index)

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\io\sas\sas7bdat.py in _chunk_to_dataframe(self)
    685                     if unit:
    686                         rslt[name] = pd.to_datetime(rslt[name], unit=unit,
--> 687                                                     origin="1960-01-01")
    688                 jb += 1
    689             elif self._column_types[j] == b's':

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py in to_datetime(arg, errors, dayfirst, yearfirst, utc, box, format, exact, unit, infer_datetime_format, origin, cache)
    590         else:
    591             from pandas import Series
--> 592             values = convert_listlike(arg._values, True, format)
    593             result = Series(values, index=arg.index, name=arg.name)
    594     elif isinstance(arg, (ABCDataFrame, compat.MutableMapping)):

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py in _convert_listlike_datetimes(arg, box, format, name, tz, unit, errors, infer_datetime_format, dayfirst, yearfirst, exact)
    201         arg = getattr(arg, 'values', arg)
    202         result = tslib.array_with_unit_to_datetime(arg, unit,
--> 203                                                    errors=errors)
    204         if box:
    205             if errors == 'ignore':

pandas\_libs\tslib.pyx in pandas._libs.tslib.array_with_unit_to_datetime()

OutOfBoundsDatetime: cannot convert input 376199.0 with the unit 'd'
```

Here is the code I'm using to chunk in:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_sas('C:\\Users\\jordan.howell\\Box\Motorcycle\\NEW MODEL DO NOT USE -EXPERIMENT\\final2019new.sas7bdat'
                 , format = 'sas7bdat', encoding='latin-1', chunksize=100000)

def chunk_preprocessing(chunk):

    columns = ['agefni', 'anti_theft_code', 'atfault', 'BI_cnt', 'BI_earned', 'bi_eu', 'bi_if', 'bi_incrd', 'bi_lae'
               , 'BI_lmt', 'cl_cnt', 'cl_incrd', 'cl_lae', 'CLded', 'cm_cnt', 'cm_incrd', 'cm_lae', 'CMded', 'cmt_cnt'
              , 'cmt_incrd', 'cmt_lae', 'cnty', 'coll_earned', 'coll_eu', 'coll_if', 'comp_earned', 'comp_eu', 'comp_if'
              , 'componly', 'DRIVER_AGE', 'dunit', 'DS_AB', 'DS_AD', 'DS_AK'
              , 'DS_AT', 'DS_CH', 'DS_DD', 'DS_DE', 'DS_DF', 'DS_FP', 'DS_FQ', 'ds_gd', 'DS_IP', 'DS_KS', 'DS_LB', 'DS_LY'
              , 'DS_MC', 'DS_ME', 'DS_ML', 'DS_MM', 'DS_MO', 'DS_MP', 'DS_MR', 'DS_MT', 'DS_MV', 'DS_PD', 'DS_PF', 'DS_PN'
              , 'DS_PF', 'DS_PY', 'DS_RP', 'DS_SB', 'DS_SF', 'DS_SP', 'DS_ST', 'DS_TP', 'DS_TR','effyear', 'FIN_RESP_CD'
              , 'majorvio', 'MARITAL_STATUS', 'minorvio', 'mp_cnt', 'mp_earned', 'mp_eu', 'mp_if', 'mp_lae', 'mp_cnt'
              , 'MPlmt', 'MVEH_CC', 'mveh_pkg_typ_cd', 'payplan', 'pd_cnt', 'pd_earned', 'pd_eu', 'pd_if', 'pd_incrd'
              , 'pd_lae', 'PDlmt', 'policy', 'polterm', 'prdtype', 'producer', 'RATING_CLASS_CODE', 'risk'
              , 'score', 'SD_AB', 'SD_SB', 'SD_TP, SD_TR', 'ST_AD', 'ST_AI', 'ST_CI', 'ST_DD', 'ST_DF', 'ST_MF', 'ST_MI'
              , 'ST_MS', 'ST_RC', 'ST_RI', 'state', 'stored_locked_ind', 'term', 'terr', 'totalep', 'TOTL_YRS_LCNS_CNT'
              , 'um_cnt', 'um_earned', 'um_eu', 'um_if', 'um_incrd', 'um_lae', 'unit_drv_exp', 'units'
              , 'unitval', 'unitzip', 'v_age', 'yrs_owned']

    chunk = chunk[columns]

    return chunk

chunk_list = []

for chunk in df:
    chunk_filter =chunk_preprocessing(chunk)
    chunk_list.append(chunk)

df_concat = pd.concat(chunk_list)
```

I can't even tell if I'm chunking correctly.

Comment: So does your SAS dataset have any variables with DATE or DATETIME formats attached or not?  Is the issue that you are getting the error even though you are trying to ignore those columns?  I suspect that under the hood `read_sas` has to read every variable, even those you don't want returned to your dataframe.

Comment: ahhh.  Yes there is date variables but not the ones I chose.  I will drop those columns in the SAS dataset then try again.  Thank you.