# Dask Data Frame OutOfBoundsDatetime Error

Tags: pandas, dask, dask-distributed, dask-dataframe

I'm getting the following error while trying to perform operations on a `datetime[ns]` column in the `Dask` data frame:

> OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 3019-01-31 00:00:00

The operations I'm trying to perform are:

```
[1] print(df_calls['CALL_TS'].min().compute(), df_calls['CALL_TS'].max().compute())

[2] pd.concat([df_calls.isnull().sum().compute(), df_calls.isnull().sum().compute()/len(df_calls)],1)\
.rename(columns={0:'count', 1:'fraction'})
```

when I try to get `min` and `max` on the `pandas` data frame, it works, so why it is not working on `dask` data frame.

The min and max date in `CALL_TS` are: `2018-03-26; 2020-12-30`.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Have you seen [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42107377/importing-datetimes-to-pandas-dataframe-raises-outofboundsdatetime-error)?

Comment: Please add a sample of data and complete code

Comment: and the full traceback